# object Object en select inputs datatables

Tags: datatables

resulta que implemente el select input y funciona bien en todas las columnas, exceptuando una.
Me muestra [object Object] en el selector de dicha columna.

```
{
  "sClass": "alignRight",
  "data" : null,
  'render': function (data, type, row, meta) {
  var nombre = row['nombre'];   
  var apellido = row['apellido'];   
  return ' ' + nombre + ' '+apellido+' ';
  }                 
}
```

es en esta columna en donde obtengo [object Object] cuando deberian aparecer el nombre y apellido de los usuarios.
la llamada de ejecuta por ajax y devuelve un json.
lei por ahi que no habria que usar 'render', pero en ese caso, como llamo a las variables nombre y apellido.
si alguien pudiera orientarme, se los agradeceria.
saludos.

Comment: Prueba a poner lo siguiente en la función render: `console.log(JSON.stringify(row))` y mira lo que te aparece en la consola del navegador

Comment: pablo, me muestra el "nombre" y "apellido" del usuario en cuestion, es decir datos correctos segun muestreo.

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir lo que te muestra a la pregunta? Es por comprobar que los datos están y que además están en la forma esperada

Comment: @PabloLozano lamento mucho la demora en la respuesta a tu comentario.
me di cuenta que ese dato no me era necesario en ese momento, por lo mismo, obvie llamarlo, ya que en los informes finales es donde debia aparecer.
gracias por tus comentarios y ayuda. saludos.

Comment: No te preocupes, la demora te afecta a tí, no a mí (la página ya me notifica cualquier comentario, no pienses que me quedo esperando)